# Send sms in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, sms, sms-gateway

When I am sending sms response is always show an empty JsonNode in postman

my code is

```
function sendmessage(){
        $mobileNo=$this->input->post('mobile');
        $channel='';
        $pass='';
        $password=base64_encode($pass);
        $message='Hello, This is a test message';
    
        $postData=array([
                  'channel' =>array(
                       'channel' =>  $channel,
                       'password' => $password,
                     ),
                  'messages'=>array(
                        'text'=>$message,
                        'msisdn'=>$mobileNo,
                        "source"=>"littlebloom",
                      )
            ]);
    $dataread=json_encode($postData);
    


/* API URL*/
      $url="https://secure-gw.fasthub.co.tz/fasthub/messaging/json/api";
/* init the resource */
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $dataread,
      ));
      /* Ignore SSL certificate verification */
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      /* get response */
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      /* Print error if any */
      if(curl_errno($ch))
      {
        $array=array( 'error'=> curl_error($ch));
        echo json_encode($array);
      }
      else{
        $array = array(
          "message"    => $output
        );
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      //MESSAGE CODE END
      echo $output;
}
```

This is my function for sending sms in codeigniter. Client give url of FastHub  sms service provide and also give the Json request code which is following given. I am using this in postman when i use this the json as row at given url it gives successfull msg but when i use my codeigniter code  its show error "Empty JsonNode".
how can i define this json in my code.

sms service provider is FastHub

and its `json` request is like

```
"channel":{
       "channel":113474,
       "password":"Base64(sha-256(plain_password))"
  },
"messages":[
   {
      "text":"test message",
      "msisdn":"255754088816",
      "source":"TEST"
   }
]
}
```

How can I send this type of json in $postData...

Comment: You forgot to set the content type of the curl request to application/json

Answer (score 1):

Try to set content-type to JSON add this under $ch variable. somewhere after or before other setopts

`$headers = array( "Content-Type: application/json", ); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`